# Properties of Lebesgue Integration

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am completely stuck with the following problem on Lebesgue Integration:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d \to [0, +\infty]$ be measurable.

1. Show that if $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x)dx < \infty$, then $f$ is finite almost everywhere. Give a counterexample to show that the converse statement is false.
2. Show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x)dx=0$ if and only if $f$ is zero almost everywhere.

All I know is the definition of a measurable function:

An unsigned function $f:\mathbb{R}^d \to [0, +\infty]$ is *unsigned Lebesgue measurable*, or *measurable* for short, if it is the point-wise limit of unsigned simple functions, i.e., if there exists a sequence $f_1,f_2,f_3, \ldots : \mathbb{R}^d \to [0, +\infty]$ of unsigned simple functions such that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

How would I be able to use this to my advantage in order to solve the problem at hand? Thank you in advance for helping me with these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove your statements we will use the following

> **Proposition** (*Markov inequality*): Let $f$ be a *positive* measurable function, then for all $a > 0$ we have
>   $$\mu\{x \in E: f(x)>a \}\le\frac{1}{a}\int fd\mu$$
>   Where $E$ is a measurable set where $f$ is defined.

*Proof*

Define $A_a:=\{ x\in E:f(x)>a\}$ (that is the set we want to measure). Then we see that

$$f(x) \ge a\Bbb{1}_{A_a}$$

Where $\Bbb{1}_{A_a}:= \begin{cases} 1, & \text{ if } x \in A_a \\0, &\text{else}\end{cases}$. Indeed if $x \in A_a$ then we have $f(x) \ge a$ by definition of $A_a$ and otherwise $f(x) \ge 0$, which is true since $f$ is a positive function. Now integrate both sides to get

\begin{align*}\int f d\mu &\ge a\int \Bbb{1}_{A_a} d\mu \\
&\ge a\mu (A_a) \implies \mu(A_a) \le\frac{1}{a} \int f d\mu\end{align*}
as we wanted.

Now to prove the statement

> $$\int_E fd\mu \lt \infty \implies f \lt \infty$$
>   if $f$ is positive and measurable

what we want to do is to measure the set where $f$ *is not finite*. Ideally we want that set to have measure $0$, so that we know that our function does not take infinite values.

Define then for all $n \ge 1$, $A_n:= \{x \in E:f(x) \ge n \}$, $A_{\infty}:=\{x \in E: f(x) = \infty \}$. Note that $A_{\infty}$ is the intersection over all $n$ of $A_n$. Hence we have

$$\mu \left(A_{\infty}\right)= \mu \left(\bigcap_{n\ge 1}A_n\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \mu(A_n) \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \int f d\mu\to 0\qquad(n\to \infty)$$

Where we first use the fact that the intersection of the $A_n$ is a decreasing intersection and where we used the proposition above to approximate the measure of $A_n$. Now you are done, since the measure of $A_{\infty}$ is zero and therefore you know that $f$ does not take infinite values.

To prove the statement

> for $f$ positive and measurable
>   $$\int f d \mu = 0 \iff f =0\qquad a.e$$

You need to prove two directions. If you have $f=0$ almost everywhere then it's quite easy, but if you don't know how to do it ask. The other direction is a little bit more difficult, but as above the idea is to measure the set where $f$ takes value *bigger than 0*. We want that set to have measure $0$. Define then for all $n \ge 1$ $B_n := \{ x \in E: f(x) \ge \frac{1}{n}\}$. Again using the proposition above we get

$$\mu(B_n) \le n \underbrace{\int f d\mu}_{=0}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the very detailed response, I think I understand what you did in the first proposition; in fact, I believe it is called, or at least looks like, what my textbook calls Markov's Inequality. As for the two-directional proof, I would assume that the starting point of $f=0$ almost everywhere would imply that $f$ is defined on a set of measure zero. However, I am stuck with how to proceed in this direction, that is, if it is the right one to go in.

Comment: @Jamil_V No problem. You are right. The proposition is called *Markov Inequality*. For the other direction you have that $f = 0$ $\mu a.e$ that is *the set where f takes value different from $0$ * has **measure $0$**. You know that if $f$ takes a finite number of values on different sets $A_i$ than $f$ is called a *simple function* and his integral is $\int f d \mu  = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \mu(A_i)$ where $a_i$ are the values of $f$. Now your function is $0$ almost every and by convention $a_i \cdot \mu(A_i)=0$ if $a_i =0$ and $\mu(A_i)=\infty$.

Comment: @Jamil_V this is pretty intuitive if you think about it. A function with value $0$ gets a integral $=0$ on whatever set you integrate it. In your case $f$ is measurable and positive, but you know that the integral of $f$ is defined as $\int f d\mu = \sup_{h \text{ simple } h \le f} \int h d\mu$ but if $f$ is zero almost everywhere, so is $h$ and there you can use the fact that $0\cdot \infty =0$

Comment: I just want to know how $A_{\infty}$ is a decreasing intersection over all $n$ of $A_n$. The definition for $A_n$ says that $f(x) \geq n$ and $A_{\infty}$ says that $f(x)=\infty$.

Comment: @Jamil_V nice question! To understand that i suggest you to draw a function $f$ defined from $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}^+$. Now mark with a colour, say orange, all the points on the $x-axis$ that belong to $A_1$, that is all the point $x\in \Bbb{R}$ for which $f(x) \gt 1$. Do the same, this time with another colour, say red, to mark all the points that belong to $A_2$, that is all the points $x\in \Bbb{R}: f(x) \gt 2$, do the same for $A_3, A_4,\dots,$ until you see the picture. What you can see is that increasing the value of $n$ the "size" of the $A_n$ *decrease*, and that

Comment: @Jamil_V **most importantly** every point $x \in \Bbb{R}$ that is in $A_{n+1}$ is also in $A_i$ for $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$. From this fact you notice that if you intersect $A_{n+1} \cap A_n$ you get $A_{n+1}$, but this is nothing more than the definition of decreasing sequence of sets. Do you get it?

Comment: Yes! I believe I do get it! Thank you very much for this explanation. Just out of curiosity, would you be able to assist me in another problem that has some relevance to measurable functions and simple unsigned functions. If so, you can find it on my profile and it is titled Measuring Unsigned Simple Functions. Again, I greatly appreciate your help and concise explanations.

Comment: @Jamil_V No problem! Glad this helped you. I'll check it out, i'm a student as well as you so i do not assure you that i can help you with the other problem, but i will study it nevertheless ;D Have a nice day!